# CancellationToken with async Dapper methods?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dapper, cancellation-token

I'm using Dapper 1.31 from Nuget. I have this very simple code snippet,

```
string connString = "";
string query = "";
int val = 0;
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    val = (await conn.QueryAsync<int>(query, tokenSource.Token)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

When I press <kbd>F12</kbd> on `QueryAsync`, it points me to

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>
     (
        this IDbConnection cnn, 
        string sql, 
        dynamic param = null, 
        IDbTransaction transaction = null, 
        int? commandTimeout = null, 
        CommandType? commandType = null
     );
```

There is no `CancellationToken` on its signature.

Questions:

- Why is the snippet completely buildable *assuming* that there is no compiler error on the whole solution?
- Forgive me that I cannot test if calling `tokenSource.Cancel()` would really cancel the method because I don't know how to generate a long running sql query. Will the `.Cancel()` really cancel the method and throw `OperationCancelledException`?

Thank you!

Comment: `dynamic param` will take pretty much anything. What you're doing is kind of like passing a cancellation token as a parameter to `Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])`. Just because you can pass it doesn't mean the function supports cancellation.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You are passing the cancellation token as the parameter object; that won't work.

The first async methods in dapper did not expose a cancellation token; when I tried to add them as an optional parameter (as a separate overload, to avoid breaking existing assemblies), [things got very confused with "ambiguous method" compilation problems](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/08/optional-parameters-considered-harmful.html). Consequently, I had to expose this via a separate API; enter `CommandDefinition`:

```
val = (await conn.QueryAsync<int>(
    new CommandDefinition(query, cancellationToken: tokenSource.Token)
).FirstOrDefault();
```

This then passes the cancellation-token down the chain to all the expected places; it is the job of the ADO.NET provider to actually *use* it, but; it seems to work in most cases. Note that it can result in a `SqlException` rather than an `OperationCancelledException` if the operation is in progress; this again is down to the ADO.NET provider, but makes a lot of sense: you could have interrupted something important; it surfaces as a critical connection issue.

As for the questions:

> Why is the snippet completely buildable assuming that there is no compiler error on the whole solution?

Because... it is valid C#, even if it doesn't do what you expect.

> Forgive me as I cannot test if calling tokenSource.Cancel() would really cancel the method because I don't know how to generate long running sql query. Will the .Cancel() really cancels the method and throws OperationCancelledException?

ADO.NET provider-specific, but yes it usually works. As an example of "how to generate long running sql query"; the `waitfor delay` command on SQL server is somewhat useful here, and is what I use in the integration tests.

Comment: This is a great answer from the author itself. Thanks Marc for the alternative API! Well, I'm fine with catching `SqlException` rather than `OperationCancelledException`, I will handle the logic here. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pedigree I *think* I've also figured out how to make it work correctly in the primary API too.

Comment: I have another question marc and I don't know if this is still in the scope, why do you have set `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on *line 78* of [file: SqlMapperAsync.cs](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET45/SqlMapperAsync.cs)? What does it really mean? Thanks.

Comment: @Pedigree it is standard in library code; it means it doesn't need to go to the sync-context - it doesn't depend on anything like adp.net context etc. Library code should almost always use it; application code usually *should* use sync-context, so should usually omit it. In fact, if library code forgets to do this, it can sometimes cause hard deadlocks (depending on what the calling application code does)

Comment: Hi Marc. I have another followup question. Is this acceptable? `await SqlMapper.ExecuteAsync(connection, new CommandDefinition(sqlStatement, param, cancellationToken: token));` where ***param*** is the list of parameters? I'm confused why you use `object parameters = null` rather than `dynamic param = null` in the `CommandDefinition`. Does it have any difference?

Comment: @Pedigree none whatsoever; our use of `param` doesn't actually use `dynamic`; at the IL level, `dynamic` === `object`. It is only compiler magic that does things like `obj.Whatever()` in a special way, and *we don't use that*

Comment: @Pedigree in the next release of dapper, `cancellationToken` may be available on the original API; but today: it isn't

Comment: so whatever I use either *object* or *dynamic*, the result is the same. Cool! Will it correctly throws `OperationCancelledException`then?

Comment: @Pedigree that is a question for ADO.NET; as I already mentioned, it *may* surface as `SqlException` if the operation was in progress

Comment: @MarcGravell why is there no support for `CancellationToken` on the `ExecuteAsync` method? I notice it builds a `CommandDefinition` in the background and sets its `CancellationToken = default`.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix [SqlMapper.cs](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs) in [Dapper lib](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper) by adding these lines:

```
    internal IDbCommand SetupCommand(IDbConnection cnn, Action<IDbCommand, object> paramReader)
    {
        var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();

#if ASYNC
        // We will cancel our IDbCommand
        CancellationToken.Register(() => cmd.Cancel());
#endif
```

Rebuild your own Dapper lib and enjoy :)

Comment: .. and then maintain it when the Upstream accepts commits with new features/bugfixes...

Answer (score -1):

try using a `SqlConnection` and catch the exception on cancel

```
var sqlConn = db.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;
sqlConn.Open();

_cmd = new SqlCommand(textCommand, sqlConn);
_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and cancel the `SqlCommand`

```
_cmd.Cancel();
```

Answer (score -4):

I was using one `SqlConnection` for multiple threads. And then when I changed it so that each `Thread` created it's own `SqlConnection` the error disappeared.